# Path Class Loader Error When Starting App

Tags: android

In my app I am using a compatibility package so I can support fragments. My app runs fine when using the compatibility package provided my google. However my app needs to use map fragments which are not supported my google at the moment.

In a previous project I have used [this](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps) alternative and it worked fine. However in this project I receive the follow error when starting the app

```
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thetopomarket/com.thetopomarket.UI.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thetopomarket.UI.DashboardActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.thetopomarket-1.apk]
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thetopomarket.UI.DashboardActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.thetopomarket-1.apk]
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
02-29 17:57:24.614: E/AndroidRuntime(7064):     ... 11 more
02-29 17:59:58.564: I/Process(7157): Sending signal. PID: 7157 SIG: 9
```

I have tried to follow the advice in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-support-v4-googlemaps-support/browse_thread/thread/8442c6a80f668f17#) but still had now luck.

I have checked this project properties with the previous one to make sure they are the same but still the app wont even start. As always any help is much appreciated

Comment: I figured this out and forgot to answer. Now I don't know :(